# Spinner in Input Number on the left side

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to style the spinner in a

```
<input type="number"/>
```

to be on the left side instead of the default right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can do that.
All you have to do is add a direction property to the element and you're done.

```html
<input dir="rtl" type="number"/>
```

good luck with that .

Comment: If you allow the value to go negative, the negative sign will show up on the right side of the digits. This is a side-effect of rendering it in rtl, or right-to-left mode.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @LarrySilverman . In my case it did not matter as I use this on price fields, which all only allow positive numbers, even for my discount field, where I show a negative to the right, outside the input field. That might be the way to go, for others, if using this with negative numbers. Great answer, surprised not more people have found this helpful!

Comment: can something be done about the location of the negative sign?

Comment: This also left-justifies the field, FYI.

Answer (score 4):

On Chromium-based browsers you can use this non-standard trick, which will not affect the position of the negative sign.

```
[type=number]::-webkit-textfield-decoration-container {flex-direction: row-reverse}
```